# TextView with a single, editable line

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, textview

I'd like to do textual back-and-forth interaction in an Android control. The idea is to have something like this:

> This is some text output by the program.
>
> What is your name? |

with the cursor at `|` (note that editing doesn't start at the beginning of the last line). The user is then free to enter text (using whatever Android input method, keyboard, etc.) but isn't allowed to change any of the output so far. Ideally, the user's input would be styled differently.

Then, as soon as newline is entered, I want the program to be notified and editing to stopped:

> This is some text output by the program.
>
> What is your name? **Foo Bar**
>
> Hello, Foo Bar!

Note that this needs to be a proper control, i.e. one I can compose with other controls to make it just one part of the app's main layout.

Comment: I guess one thing I could do is to have an invisible `EditText` somewhere, focus that for editing, then change the main `TextView`'s content keypress-by-keypress. But that removes the user's ability to move the cursor around in the editable section.

Comment: OK, so the consensus in the answers seems to be to make a separate `TextView` for the "question" and a separate `EditText` for the "answer". So would it work to have a large `TextView` on top (containing the dialogue so far), a one-line `TextView` below it on the left, and a one-line `EditText` on its right? Will this last line be at exactly the right distance as a "proper" new paragraph of the large `TextView` would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a new LinearLayout(TextView + EditText) and assign the background of layout like EditText and edittext's no background.
Upon editText done, you could show a new TextView in the bottom

Comment: And how would I find out the coordinates of where to put the `EditText`?

Comment: Place both items (TextView and EdiText) horizontally, At the end of the TextView the EditText will start with cursor at it's start. And you can any style for your edittext as well

Answer (score 2):

Make a `TextView` and the `EditText` next to each other then your problem is solved and add the following line of code in `EditText`.

```
android:singleLine= 'true';
```

It allow only one line to be entered to the `EditText`. let me know whether this is what your expecting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="What is your Name?"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You create the EditText and align it next to the TextView you created. That should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, can't try it out right now, but will reply when I get around to it.

Answer (score 2):

> > This is some text output by the program.
> >
> > What is your name? |
>
> with the cursor at | (note that editing doesn't start at the beginning
>   of the last line). The user is then free to enter text (using whatever
>   Android input method, keyboard, etc.) but isn't allowed to change any
>   of the output so far. Ideally, the user's input would be styled
>   differently.

I would strongly recommend to rethink about your design as the same thing can be done with the help of LinearLayout,Editext,TextView with very simple and more manageable way.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `ListView` at top, to show your conversation & then below it, needs a **horizontal** view with a `TextView` (to show question) and `EditText`(with background transparent - to ask user to fill an answer).